# Не могу добавить текст введенный пользователем в базу данных Sqlite Studio в telegram bot на aiogram

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram, sqlite3

Помогите пожалуйста с такой проблемой, не получается добавить текст введенный пользователем в телеграм боте в базу данных, столбец problem, до этого все идет хорошо, id и номер телефона добавляются, в чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)